# post data not working as expected in Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, repeater

i want to delete the record with the help of Jquery. get the row id and delete that row. when the first time I click button data deleted fine but next time when jquery $.post render repeater table than click button on delte functionality not working . I don't find reason of this problem .
my jquery code

```
$(".delButton").click(function () {
        debugger;
        alert("delclick");
        var delID = $(this).parent().parent().children().html();
        $.post("CallBacks/AddProducts.aspx", { DeleteID : delID},
           function (data, status) {

                   debugger;
                   var start = data.indexOf("###Start###") + 11;
                   var end = data.indexOf("###End###");
                   var subdata= data.substring(start,end);
                   $("#productTbody").html(subdata);

               });
           });
```

and my repeater table form main class is:

```
  <tbody id="productTbody">

                    <asp:Repeater id="repeaterProducts" runat="server" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><%# Eval("id") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("ColourName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("GageName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Rate") %></td>
                        <td><input class="delButton" type="button" value="del"/></td>

                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>  



                     </tbody>
```

same repeater is use in second class AddProducts

```
  ###Start###   
               <asp:Repeater id="repeaterProducts" runat="server" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><%# Eval("id") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("ColourName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("GageName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Rate") %></td>
                        <td><input class="delButton" type="button" value="del"/></td>

                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>  

 ###End###
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate the click event, instead of:

```
$(".delButton").click(function () {
```

Do:

```
$(document).on('click', '#delButton', function () {
```

This way, the event is bound to the document, so when your elements are re-rendered, they'll still be found - and your clicks will work.

Comment: now the problem is when ever I click on other events they call this function even they have no class .delButton

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `on`, i should have written that in the first place.

Comment: No worries, do tick the answer if it answered the question.